# BS4 getText function producing unexpected output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The Following html sample produces different results depending on the text style format
Here is the sample when on one line

```
card = """
<ul class="wrapper--inline-block float--left margin-top--15 padding-left--20 font--weight-300"><li><span class="font--weight-500">Minimum Qualification:</span> Bachelor</li><li><span class="font--weight-500">Experience Level:</span> Graduate trainee</li><li><span class="font--weight-500">Experience Length:</span> 1 year</li></ul>
"""
```

Output:

```
Minimum Qualification: BachelorExperience Level: Graduate traineeExperience Length: 1 year
```

And when the html sample is formatted

```
card = """
<ul class="wrapper--inline-block float--left margin-top--15 padding-left--20 font--weight-300">
<li><span class="font--weight-500">Minimum Qualification:</span> Bachelor</li>
<li><span class="font--weight-500">Experience Level:</span> Graduate trainee</li>
<li><span class="font--weight-500">Experience Length:</span> 1 year</li>
</ul>
"""
```

**The Output**

```
Minimum Qualification: Bachelor
Experience Level: Graduate trainee
Experience Length: 1 year
```

Question is, how can make the first case produce the desired output like case two.
Here is my current code

```
qualifications=  BeautifulSoup(card, "html.parser")
print(qualifications.getText())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `separator="\n"` to get desired output,

```
qualifications.getText(separator="\n")
```

**Edit-1:**

```
>>> card = """
<ul class="wrapper--inline-block float--left margin-top--15 padding-left--20 font--weight-300"><li><span class="font--weight-500">Minimum Qualification:</span> Bachelor</li><li><span class="font--weight-500">Experience Level:</span> Graduate trainee</li><li><span class="font--weight-500">Experience Length:</span> 1 year</li></ul>
"""

>>> qualifications=  BeautifulSoup(card, "html.parser")

>>> for li in qualifications.find_all('li'):
     print(li.get_text()) 
Minimum Qualification: Bachelor
Experience Level: Graduate trainee
Experience Length: 1 year
```

Comment: That one produces every element on  a new line even the one with span tag

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the case for bs4 prints the contents the same way it gets it(in one line or in different line). But for your specific question you can first find `<li>` tags and then print their content. The whole contents of each element will be printed in a different line.

```
qualifications=  BeautifulSoup(card, "html.parser")
soup = qualifications.findAll('li')
for i in soup:
     print(i.getText())
```

you'll get this:

```
Minimum Qualification: Bachelor
Experience Level: Graduate trainee
Experience Length: 1 year
```